# Site navigation from Google not using HTTPS for some resources, causing redirect loop

Tags: plugins, ssl

**Issue**: My site runs into a redirect loop when accessed via Google search results, but not when accessing the same page manually, or when navigating the site on its own.

I have done some investigation and I find that some of the CSS file resources that are being referenced in the page source are not using HTTPS when accessed from Google, but the same files *are* loaded with HTTPS when navigating to the same page from within the site itself.

I use the Really Simple SSL plugin and the site experienced redirect looping from Google, but if I turn off the "WordPress 301 redirection to SSL" setting within the plugin, the site will load but the CSS files are blocked.

My "Wordpress URL" and "Site URL" are set correctly (both say "https:// example.com**), and I can't remember making any changes recently that would cause this to come up.

Any thoughts on why CSS files loaded from Google search results would use HTTP, and the same files loaded from navigation within the site would use HTTPS? My best guess is that the HTTP files loaded from Google are what's causing the redirect loop.

Comment: How are the resources added to the page? Are you using the wp_enqueue_style() function?

Comment: @Sephsekla I am not sure. I recently took over managing the site and don't have a lot of experience with Wordpress. How might I find this?